# How to create a robust data pipeline from external data source to hive using oozie?

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

Here are my requirements -

1. Get the incremental data into hive external table (t_incr) from RDBMS using sqoop
2. Join Incremental (t_incr) and base table (t_base) data then dedup it and store it in hive as a table (t_merged)
3. Take the backup of base table as (t_base_bkup)
4. If t_merged has more or   equal rows than/to t_base_bkup then only move to next step
5. Replace  the base table (t_base) data with merged table (t_merged) data

I am able to create this workflow using oozie without step 4.

Can anyone suggest how to incorporate step 4 in oozie workflow?

Note : Step 4 is just to make sure that I dont lose any data while in step 5

Oozie Version : 4.2
Hive Version  : 1.2